# Get the actual row number of QTableView after drag and drop

Tags: c++, qt5

At first, the data of the tableview are

1. apple
2. pie
3. banana

After drag and drop(only drag and drop on itself) the item on the tableview, the data of the tableview looks like following

1. banana
2. pie
3. apple

but when I want to iterate the item of the model one by one

codes

```
for(int i = 0; i != rowCount(); ++i){
    if(item(row, Fruit)){
        return item(row, Fruit)->data(Qt::DisplayRole).value<QString>();
    }        
}
```

it print the data as

1. apple
2. pie
3. banana

expected result

1. banana
2. pie
3. apple

How could I get the “actual” number after drag and drop?

The easiest solution I can think of is create one more column to store the row number of the model, then override the dropEvent, update the row number when the user drop their row.Any easier way to do it?

Edit :

[image: Example]

As the example show, the result I want with the codes is "pie, apple, banana".But the actual result is "banana, pie, apple"

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your code prints wrong result when QTableView itself shows correct order? Or you call your code before drag&drop is fully finished?

Comment: @Bogdan The result of the view is correct, but when I iterate through the items, the order is not what I want(it follow the order of the vertical header view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model always operates on the logicalIndex. You need to use the visualIndex of the verticalHeader() for iterating.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount(); ++i)
  {
    // i is the logicalIndex
    int row = your_table->verticalHeader()->visualIndex(i);

    if(item(row, Fruit))
        return item(row, Fruit)->data(Qt::DisplayRole).value<QString>();     
  }
```